# ggmap: gives error when using open street map as source

Tags: r, openstreetmap, ggmap

I'm new to R and I'm following this [article](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf) to learn ggmap.

```
qmap("Forbidden city",zoom=15)
qmap("Forbidden city",zoom=15, source="osm")
```

While the first command above works perfectly, the second one gives me an error info:

> Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Forbidden+city&    zoom=15&size=%20640x640&maptype=terrain&sensor=false
>   Google Maps API Terms of Service : http://developers.google.com/maps/terms
>   Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Forbidden+city&sensor=false
>   Google Maps API Terms of Service : http://developers.google.com/maps/terms
>   Error: map grabbing failed - see details in ?get_openstreetmap.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
>     cannot open: HTTP status was '503 Service Unavailable'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: works for me. Maybe the API was down...

Comment: Voting to close because access to the Google Maps API has changed as of July 2018. An API key is now required to make a Google Maps request, so this question is no longer reproducible in it's current form.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error, reproducibly.

I think this is to do with the `zoom=...` specification. This argument is interprested differently depending on the `source`. When you specify `source="osm"` the call is routed to `get_openstreetmap(...)`. According to the documentation for that function:

> ...if you get an error when downloading an openstreetmap the error is
>   attributable to an improper scale specification...

The `zoom` parameter influences the scale specification if `scale="auto"` (the default). So basically, if `zoom` is too large the call will throw an error. I get errors with zoom > 13 for the Forbidden City, but this works:

```
qmap("Forbidden city",zoom=13, source="osm")
```